# Compare Two Files in Linux

Tags: bash, python

I am trying to compare file A with pattern file B and show the matched lines of file A. `X` can be replaced by `0` and `1` in file B. File A does not contain any don't cares. File B is a large file.

For example:

File A:

```
010101

011111

000000

111111
```

File B:

```
X11XX1

01010X

000000
```

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve.  If you were to compare files A and B as written what would be the output of the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

To find the lines of fileA which match any of the patterns in fileB where X is interpreted as a wildcard:

```
$ grep -f <(tr X . <fileB) fileA
010101
011111
000000
111111
```

`<(tr X . <fileB)` creates a file-like object that has all the `X` replaced with `.`.  In regular expressions, `.` is a wildcard.

`grep -f <(tr X . <fileB) fileA` reads patterns from our file-like object and will only print lines from fileA that match one of those patterns.